# "coefficient may be infinite" even with non-zero events

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, hazard

I'm performing survival analysis for a couple of very simple datasets:

```
dt.pat1 <- data.frame(
  Marker=c(F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,T,T,T),
  Event=c(F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,F,F,F,F,T,F,T,T,T,T,T),
  days=c(30,42,164,168,169,196,197,231,234,249,260,331,370,408,454,486,577,101,183,190,314,328)
)

dt.pat2 <- data.frame(
  Marker=c(F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,T,T),
  Event=c(F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,T,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,F,T),
  days=c(41,111,136,150,163,172,175,209,228,245,246,294,297,298,321,357,358,372,441,447,478,505,106,153,155,189)
)
```

For the first one, it is very straightforward with `surv_fit()` and `coxph()`:

```
dt.pat_this <- dt.pat1
fit_obj  <- surv_fit(Surv(days,Event) ~ Marker, data = dt.pat_this)
ggsurvplot(fit = fit_obj, data = dt.pat_this, risk.table=T)
summary(coxph(fit_obj$call$formula, data=dt.pat_this))
# Call:
#   coxph(formula = fit_obj$call$formula, data = dt.pat_this)
# 
# n= 22, number of events= 9 
# 
# coef exp(coef) se(coef)    z Pr(>|z|)  
# MarkerTRUE 1.8005    6.0528   0.7348 2.45   0.0143 *
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
# MarkerTRUE     6.053     0.1652     1.434     25.55
# 
# Concordance= 0.712  (se = 0.09 )
# Likelihood ratio test= 6.14  on 1 df,   p=0.01
# Wald test            = 6  on 1 df,   p=0.01
# Score (logrank) test = 7.76  on 1 df,   p=0.005
#
```

[image: Cohort1]
Reporting: HR=6.1, 95% CI: 1.4-25.6, p=0.0143

For the second set (`dt.pat2`), the plot looks totally fine but Cox PH summary is not so nice:

```
# Call:
#   coxph(formula = fit_obj$call$formula, data = dt.pat_this)
# 
# n= 26, number of events= 7 
# 
# coef exp(coef)  se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)
# MarkerTRUE 2.236e+01 5.119e+09 1.397e+04 0.002    0.999
# 
# exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
# MarkerTRUE 5.119e+09  1.953e-10         0       Inf
# 
# Concordance= 0.755  (se = 0.08 )
# Likelihood ratio test= 13.1  on 1 df,   p=3e-04
# Wald test            = 0  on 1 df,   p=1
# Score (logrank) test = 22.01  on 1 df,   p=3e-06
# 
# Warning message:
#   In coxph.fit(X, Y, istrat, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
#                  Loglik converged before variable  1 ; coefficient may be infinite.
```

[image: Cohort2]

I previously thought this happens when there's no events in one of the groups, but apparently even having few events can cause problems? What metrics would you recommend reporting in such case? For now, I resort to using `coxphf()` instead of `coxph()` - is there any better approach?

Comment: There are many events in one group beyond time=200 and none in the other group. (I'd consider that the warning is correct in this case. How were you going to report a relative hazard of 5 billion, anyway? I would consider that effectively an infinite coefficient estimate.) This warning has been discussed before although you example has the converse problem, i.e the warning looks correct.

Comment: sure I was not going to report crazy HR numbers, that's why I asked for advise of what should I use in this situation

Comment: I never realized I needed to have events not only in each arm, but also in a specific time window!

Comment: I would just say that the difference is survival is so extreme that the estimated relative hazard was "numerically infinite", i.e. not a meaningful number other than "really, really big". I think you could test whether the large number of events in a single cohort in the latter stages of observation was the source of the warning by stopping the analysis at  some earlier time, say 250.

Comment: ok thanks, that makes sense. Though it's harder for me to interpret very high p-value in the same way.  And it's weird for me that just shifting the last timepoint by 1 day (which is now `189`) in `dt.pat2` makes all the difference: if I set it as `208` or lower, then p=0.999, and with `209` I get p=0.003!

Comment: In a very real sense the data is pathological from a numeric perspective. You are trying to assign a number to relative hazard in an overall process where there is no comparison group for a large part of the time. You could probably get a Weibull model to fit curves to both cohorts, but the results will be basically the same: huge difference and unequivocal statistics saying they are significant.

Comment: Maybe this should be posed as a question on stats.stackexchange.com where  real statisticians can then opine and advise on how they have such problems (all the events in one group happen after the last event in another group) in the past. You can't be the only person to have experienced this. I will say that there is one defective aspect of your question ...... no `library` call to load a package with a `surv_fit` function.

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed in the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survival/versions/3.4-0/topics/coxph) of the `coxph()` function.

> In certain data cases the actual MLE estimate of a coefficient is infinity, e.g., a dichotomous variable where one of the groups has no events. When this happens the associated coefficient grows at a steady pace and a race condition will exist in the fitting routine: either the log likelihood converges, the information matrix becomes effectively singular, an argument to exp becomes too large for the computer hardware, or the maximum number of interactions is exceeded. (Most often number 1 is the first to occur.) The routine attempts to detect when this has happened, not always successfully. The primary consequence for the user is that the Wald statistic = coefficient/se(coefficient) is not valid in this case and should be ignored; the likelihood ratio and score tests remain valid however.

As suggested in the comments, this is really a statistical issue. In the second dataset all of the deaths in the `Marker = TRUE` group happen before any deaths in the `Marker = FALSE` group. (There are individuals in the other group who are censored during this time, but none who experience an event.) Therefore the estimated hazard in the `Marker = TRUE` group is infinitely higher than the hazard in the other group. The `coxph()` function successfully detects the problem in this case and issues a warning.

As described in the documentation, the p-value of 0.999 in the summary of the second model is incorrect (this is from the Wald statistic). Instead you can report the likelihood ratio test and conclude that the effect of Marker is statistically significant (p < 0.01). Reporting an estimate of the hazard ratio is nonsensical, but you can conclude the hazard is higher in the `Marker = TRUE` group.